# How do I access/change system settings on an LG webOS TV?

Tags: webos, lg

Does LG provide an API for its webOS TV that allows one to access/change system settings, the screen itself, or to bring up, for example, the screen saving menu from the settings tab?

I want to develop an app which would turn off the TV screen with one click. Currently, you cannot create any shortcuts for this action and you have to dig through the menu each time. I also cannot use the voice assistant.

I looked through the APIs and did not find anything, so it is not possible for such an app to exist?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that is available now. But I have an idea that you can take another approaching by sending the manual button input script with some delay, like:

> HOME[delay] RIGHT[delay] RIGHT[delay]  OK[delay] UP[delay]
> RIGHT[delay], RIGHT[delay],

OK . It should work. By that way you can integrate with some smart homekit around ?
This repo gives you some ideas...

https://github.com/supersaiyanmode/PyWebOSTV/